# Remove bond interface from centos permanently

Tags: linux, centos, networking, bonding

I have a Centos server having a bond interface containing two interfaces, I am trying to remove one of them from the bond.

Using `ifenslave -d bond0 eno1` it is removed
however, **after restart** the interface **reverts back** to `bond0`.

How can i make this change permanent?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Networkmanager. Configure Networkmanager according to your needs.

Networkmanager is all about "connection" profiles. See the profiles you have with `nmcli connection`. Then delete the ones you don't want anymore with `nmcli connection delete "$PROFILENAME"`.